# executeUpdate insert query returns 0 but works when inserted manually

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I have multiple instances of preparedStatements, all of them works and all are 
committed. Except this code block does not work:

```
public static int InsertBatchProcessingLogs(Connection con, Data dt) {
    int batchID = -1;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

    try {
        System.out.println("INSERT INTO BATCH PROCESSING LOGS");
        preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement("insert into batch_processing_logs (batchID, targetMSISDN,plancode,createddate) select ?,targetMSISDN,plancode,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP from batch_list_tbl where scheduleID = ? and batch_list_status = 1",1);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, dt.getValue("batchID"));
        preparedStatement.setString(2, dt.getValue("scheduleID"));
        batchID = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        // batchID = preparedStatement.executeUpdate("insert into batch_processing_logs (batchID, targetMSISDN,plancode,createddate) select "+dt.getValue("batchID")+",targetMSISDN,plancode,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP from batch_list_tbl where scheduleID = "+dt.getValue("batchID")+" "
        // +" and batch_list_status = 1");
        con.commit();
        System.out.println("INSERT QUERY: " + batchID);

        if (batchID > 0) {
           System.out.println("INSERT BATCH LOGS SUCCESSFUL" +dt.getValue("batchID")+dt.getValue("scheduleID"));
        } else {
            System.out.println("FAILED EXECUTIONS OF INSERT BATCH LOGS");
            System.out.println(preparedStatement);
        }
    } catch (Exception exprep) {
        System.out.println(exprep);
        // Log("InsertBatchProcessingLogs Exception:" + exprep.getMessage());
        exprep.printStackTrace();
        batchID = -1;
    }
    return batchID;
}
```

It always returns 0. As you can see, there's a print of the preparedStatement so when i try to query that manually, it works perfectly. I dont know why it does not work on executeUpdate() :( It also does not printStackTrace, no errors being shown. I tried a lot even the commented lines and it still does not work. Im not sure if im looking at the wrong place or not. I also tried setAutoCommit(false) then committing it after the executedUpdate. Also tried setAutoCommit(true) and removed the con.commit() code.

Comment: What is the autogenerated column in batch_processing_logs?

Comment: What is the JDBC version you are using?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson may i ask how is it relevant? Autogenerated columns were not included in the query.

Comment: @CS_noob im currently using ojdbc14

Comment: Just wanted to make sure it wasn't some mistake since you have one column namned batchID and your return value is also named batchID.

Comment: Oh sorry @JoakimDanielson my code was misleading.

Comment: I would recommend using the constant defined in `Statement` for returning the auto generated key rather than 1 in the call to prepareStatement, it might not fix your issue but the code gets clearer and is less error prone

Comment: Ok so i gave up on using executeUpdate(). I tried using JdbcTemplate.update(sqlQuery) and it works. i still dont know why PreparedStatement is not working though i hope someone can explain how it works.